# Ascending order of $3^a-3^b+3^c-3^d+3^e$.

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

> Let $S$ be set of all numbers of the form $3^a-3^b+3^c-3^d+3^e$ where $a>b>c>d>e>0$ are all natural numbers. If the elements of $S$ are arranged in ascending order, find the $20^{\text{th}}$ element.

I tried taking $3^e$ common:
$$n=3^e(3^{a-e}-3^{b-e}+3^{c-e}-3^{d-e}+1)$$
and said that for minimizing, both $3^e$ and the bracketed term must be minimum. For $e=1$ we a batch of numbers depending on our choice of $a,b,c,d$.

Then if I repeat the above step,i.e. take $3^d$ common and and and put $d=2$ for a batch-within-a-batch and repeat this over and over again.

This is basically equivalent to listing out all elements of $S$ by hand. Also, my gut says what I'm doing is flawed.

Any help would be awesome. Thanks!

---

P.S. This was on a practice test for a national Olympiad, so no calculators and/or programming please.

Comment: Alexey Burdin's answer does not require programming. One has to figure out that the largest $7$-digit number is ``+00-+-+`` and the smallest change that decreases it is to shift a ``-+`` one step left.

Comment: @Chrystomath I know, and I've understood his solution, but I still put that in there so any further answers don't use either of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the [balanced ternary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balanced_ternary). Further I'll use `+` for $+1$, `0` for $0$ and `-` for $-1$ digits respectively, e.g. $2\cdot 3^6-1=$`+-00000-`${}_3$ and $1000_{10}=$`++0+00+`${}_3$.

It's clear that our desired number in balanced ternary consists of `+-+-+` in that order with some `0`s between them (let me strip the trailing $0$ corresponding to $e>0$ in OP instead of $e\ge 0$ as here, for a while).
There are $1$ such $5$-digit number, ${5\choose 1}$ such $6$-digit numbers and ${6\choose 2}$ such $7$-digit numbers, giving $1+5+15=21$ numbers already. We want $20$th, so it's second last of length $7$. The last of length $7$ is `+00-+-+`${}_3$ and the second last is `+0-+0-+`${}_3=673_{10}$, so (returning to $e>0$) the answer is $673\cdot 3=2019$.

Python code [here](https://tio.run/##dVHbboMwDH3nKyJVyEkplItUTUjZjyA0pZCu2TI3SphGv56FXqBr10TKxcf28bHNsdsfsHgxdhhauSOdtCjskSIrA@KXlY5X9en5s1daEnxNz8gFTYQxEluKYcEmO67XvAjuPFJ2sXTfFkcgGAm3QgtsJNWPhD1PT/fuYIkiComemfuIq@mjdqQPC87zGb/jjjP2B/LhxWSQ2smnkf2trv4/Xf2DLtfZN67F17YVvmaA5OOgkEKcRlCpKKtvFFVlGWc1S7SPUYZCCixYNF745GIFvkuaL4vlcnPpkeMjA7227jozxdi5FN8Pl1hptPCoT7kCYJxDFPsNs1JjFXYUwk1Lwix3EFK1cmxWu2gins0/n7XxPb4Z/2I8tlaKz2AYfgE).

Comment: Except you need to multiply by $3$, i.e. $673 \times 3 = 2019$ since $e\ge1$.

Comment: (+1) Thank you! I actually had normal ternary on my mind as soon as I soon the problem, but the minus signs dissuaded me. I'd even thought of base $-3$ but left that. I'll wait for some time for other answers, if you don't mind.

Comment: Thank you both. At a contest it should be not so hard to have them all by hand in balanced ternary, maybe, not sure, as the ordering is not that obvious for me as it is for @Chrystomath.

Comment: What are the values for $a,b,c,d,e$ in your solution?

Comment: What I was working at was to figure out minimal increments: a ``+`` should be as much to the right as possible and a ``-`` as much to the left as possible.

Comment: @Oldboy the positions of not `0` digits, counted from the end ($+1$ for each within OP, as $e$ have to be $\ge 1$ -- or $e\ge 0$ within the solution main part)

Comment: @Oldboy Your solution idea works, but you missed some in your listing, like $7,6,5,2,1$, $7,6,5,3,1$, $7,6,5,3,2$ and $7,5,4,2,1$ (the last of which is the answer).